# partially differentiate $\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

How do you partially differentiate $\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}$, with respect to $y$ then $x$?

I have done it and got the answer $$\frac{y^2+yx}{\sqrt[3]{x^2-y^2}}$$

However, the answer given in my paper gives it with a $-y^2$ on the top with all the rest the same. Any help?

Comment: Try using the quotient rule for differentiating fractions.

Comment: How do you get the cube root in there?

Answer (score 0):

We should get the following steps:

\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}\right)&=\frac{-x}{(x+y)\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{-x}{(x+y)\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}\right)&=\frac{x^2-xy+y^2}{(x-y)(x+y)^2\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}\end{align}

Comment: I make out $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}\right)=\frac{-x}{(x+y)\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}$$

Comment: @Bacon My bad, misread it from WolframAlpha... Have corrected it

Comment: I see. A negative sign really can be missed anywhere!